# Does "idiot" in this context mean "stupid" or something else?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've been reading some H. P. Lovecraft stories in English (I'm not a native English speaker, BTW) and quite often the adjective "idiot" is prescribed to certain characters. But the context suggests that those characters are... unusual, not "stupid" (or at least nothing about them suggests this).

Here's a sample quote:

> “It was the eldritch scurrying of those fiend-born rats, always questing for new horrors, and determined to lead me on even unto those grinning caverns of earth’s centre where Nyarlathotep, the mad faceless god, howls blindly in the darkness to the piping of two amorphous **idiot** flute-players.” – H.P. Lovecraft’s “The Rats in the Walls”

Does the word "idiot" in the above quote refer to mental deficiencies or something else?

Comment: Are you using "mentally challenged" in the legal & psychiatric sense of "profoundly disabled in mental function or intellect" or in the more everyday meaning of "stupid"? Second, "idiot" used to mean "A person without learning; an ignorant, uneducated person; a simple or ordinary person" (OED). This is outdated and rare. However, the speaker could mean to ascribe "idiocy"  to the flute players, ie, they are of low intelligence (without meaning they have a true, medical, legal "mental condition"). Hard to judge an author's meaning from one example.

Comment: In other words, without having a better understanding of Lovecraft's style, including the types of words he uses, and the definitions he ascribes to them, I can't tell much from one sentence of his. For example, the English word *idiot* comes from the Greek ἰδιώτης, meaning "private person, person without professional knowledge, layman, ignorant, ill-informed person, in Hellenistic Greek also common man, plebeian" (OED) and such meanings have been, or were, at times, used by English speakers. Lovecraft could be using a meaning other than "mentally challenged" or the everyday stupid.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I guess I wanted to be more politically correct than was necessary. The reason I asked is because I always thought the meaning in Lovecraft's stories was more akin to "simpleton", but I've never heard the word "idiot" being used as a synonym in this case. The term "idiot" appears strangely often in Lovecrafts works (describing multiple characters over multiple stories). Again - I never felt that they are just "stupid". I was hoping someone familiar with the subject matter could confirm or deny my suspicions.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Also, I've recently seen a description of some of the characters translated into Polish (my native tongue). The translations seemed to be fan-made, and translated "idiot" to "idiota" - a very direct translation. And then, when I read the whole thing in Polish, the meaning was even weirder. I guess in a sense perhaps that's the point - after all, weirdness and horror is what H. P. Lovecraft was about... but I can't shake the feeling that this isn't the right meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *idiot* comes from the Greek *ιδιος*, meaning one's own or private. An idiot is one whose mental faculties are so limited as to exclude rational expression, so whose reasons and reasoning are permanently imprisoned within his own mind. Lovecraft posits a strange and horrifying place at the center of the earth, so I assume that the flute music is strange as well, but it's strange beyond explanation since the flautists, being idiots, couldn't explain their music were they asked about it. (Although I don't know how you could even pose a question to someone amorphous.)

Comment: Flute : chaos : idiotic : idiot

Comment: It should, perhaps, be added, that apart from _ίδιος_, the word _idiot_ does actually appear, almost as is, in Greek, too: _ιδιώτης_ (idiótis). That's a noun, whose nowadays usage is limited to connoting what in English is called the "private citizen". Originally (in ancient times, that is), the word did, however, bear a rather twofold meaning: one who didn't engage in or care for public matters, or - simply - an idiot, a foolish person. The former was considered a sign of the latter.